# Configuring SSH in Ansible

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ansible, ssh-keys

**Please note:** Although this question is specifically about how SSH configuration occurs in *Ansible*, I have a feeling that any Linux/SSH guru would understand what the Ansible docs are getting at and should be able to answer this for me.

I have three VMs I am using for an experimental Ansible setup:

- `ansible01` - an Ubuntu machine where I have just installed Ansible 1.9.2
- `db01` - an Ubuntu machine where I will eventually have a MySQL instance running
- `mq01` - an Ubuntu machine where I will eventually have a RabbitMQ instance running

I then went into `ansible01:/etc/ansible/hosts` and gave it the following static configuration:

```
[databases]
db01.example.org

[brokers]
mq01.example.org
```

I am now at the section of their documentation where [they discuss SSH keys](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_getting_started.html#your-first-commands) and I am not fully understanding what I need to do.

It says to run:

```
ssh-agent bash
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And then to try and ping all your nodes via `ansible all -m ping`. However the docs don’t say *where* I’m supposed to execute those SSH commands, and I feel like there’s got to be more to it than just that.

So I ask: **Where am I supposed to be creating SSH keys, and what *exact* commands do I need to run (and on which servers) so that `ansible all -m ping` will ping both my `db01` and `mq01` machines?**

---

#### Update

When I SSH into `ansible01` and run those SSH commands, here's the output:

```
myuser@ansible01:~$ ssh-agent bash
myuser@ansible01:~$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Seems as though you need to create the key-pair. 
You can do so using the following command: ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 
Source: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/
When you create that key, you will end up with ~/.ssh/id_rsa and ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
cat the ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub and SSH to each machine individually, and create a file called ~/.ssh/authorized_keys and paste the output from the public key into it. You should be golden at that point. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should create the SSH keys to your user's .ssh directory, commonly found in:

```
~/.ssh/
```

Which means you should have the following file on ansible01:

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

From your ansible01 machine you will need to run the command:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The above command sets it so that your SSH automatically looks to use the private key, id_rsa, when initiating an SSH session (which is what Ansible runs on by default). You can have add that command to your .bash_profile to have it run automatically each time you initiate a new bash session.

To ping **all** of the machines defined in your host inventory using Ansible you would run the following command:

```
ansible all -m ping
```

As to your question on which machine you should run the ping command on? This would be your machine which you have installed Ansible on- in your case **ansible01**

Comment: Thanks @user2321289 (+1) however I'm still not seeing the forest through the trees here. If I understand you correctly (please clarify if I'm still misunderstanding!), you're saying that I run `ssh-agent bash; ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` on `ansible01`, and that will give me the ability to run `ansible all -m ping`, which should ping my `db01` and `mq01` servers, **yes?!?!** If so, *how is this possible?*...

Comment: Unless I configure `db01` and `mq01` to accept SSH connections from `ansible01`, how can Ansible ever make a successful connection to these machines, especially when the ping command doesn't mentioned username/password/etc.?

Comment: In other words, without doing *something* on `db01` and `mq01`, I don't see how Ansible could connect to them. If I `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` on my laptop and then try to SSH into, say, some corporate linux server, I'm not going to be able to (unless I have the right SSH key on my laptop that is compatible with an SSH key on that server, or if I specify the username/password such as `ssh someuser@somesecretmachine`, etc.).

Comment: Think of ~/.ssh/id_rsa as your credentials in this case. In most realistic settings, you would not be using a username/password to SSH to a machine, but an RSA keypair. The machines that you mentioned, db01 and mq01 should each have a file called ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, which contains the content of your id_rsa.pub, or the public key from your keypair. 
id_rsa unlocks this public key and allows Ansible (or SSH) to authenticate without having to provide a password. This is actually more secure than using a password. Hope that helps.

Comment: Essentially on your end, you would have to do something, though. You will need to add the content of ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to each machine's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. This would be for the user which you plan on having Ansible use on each machine. 
e.g if your user is ubuntu, then under /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys you would have the public key for your id_rsa in that file.

Comment: Thanks again @user2321289 (+1 for both) - please see my update. I tried running those commands on `ansible01` and ran into trouble. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the documentation is not very clear and your problem is really an SSH problem and not an ansible one. To use SSH with key based logon you need to generate a keypair and copy the public key to the authorized_keys file on each machine you want to access. If your private key has a password you will need to key that each time you use SSH or use ssh-agent as you have described to save the private key password in your current session.

You also need to set up the known_hosts file on each machine you want to connect to or ansible will not be able to connect. There are lots of write ups on this, look for "key based ssh logon".  Before attempting to use ansible you need to be able connect via SSH using either key based or certificate based logon. Once you have that working try ansible again.